# like does not work case insensitive Postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.1

The aim is to create a duplicate check of companies. And present suspicious records for further action.

This is done by a self join and all is well as long as there is an EXACT match (case sensitive). But 'Test' and 'test' is suspicious and should be listed. A fiddle to show the problem:

```
WHERE a.name ILIKE b.name
```

The above code is not case insensitive. Test and test is not shown.

The output should be (regardless of number of duplicated records):

```
1   Test  5 tesT
3   Testa 4 Testa
```

Modified the fiddle with 5 records.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2c723/1

Thank you in advance for all clues to make an insensitive self join search!

Comment: can you add the SQL statements to your question please? SQLFiddle is not working right now (at least not for me). Did you try `lower(a.name) = lower(b.name)`?

Comment: Yes, lower does not work either.

Comment: Try a different approach: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e758/2

Comment: Thank you! The goal is to get two rows with "duplicates". Each row with both id and name to compare. I cannot figure out how to manage it with this approach. I will investigate this further, but I cannot see any obvious solution.

Comment: Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e758/4

Comment: Adding another record breaks this code. Though I was impress by its simplicity. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2c723/1 It should still be two rows max

Comment: Again: please **edit** your question and add the sample data the expected output based on your sample data. Do you need the `id` column with the duplicates? Can the list of duplicates be a comma separated "single" value?

Comment: Done. I need both the id from first and last match. The result should generated as a normal fetch.

Comment: The output won't work with your updated data  (if you have three values for `test`) because you can't have a different number of columns in different rows. Would something like this be suitable: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b87af/4

Comment: Elegant and correct solution. Thank you. The problem is mostly how I do the next step. 1. Present it on the screen for decision. 2. Get id and merge one company into another. Therefore I want only two at a time and ID easy to get and companies in separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution based on a simple join:

```
create table co (id int4, name varchar(30));
insert into co values 
(1,'Test'),
(2,'test'),
(3,'Testa'),
(4,'Testa'),
(5,'testT');

SELECT min(a.id),a.name,max(b.id), b.name FROM co a
LEFT JOIN co b ON lower(a.name) = lower(b.name)
WHERE a.id<b.id
GROUP BY a.name,b.name;
```

The output was this:

```
1|Test|2|test
3|Testa|4|Testa
```

The goal was to present 2 duplicates at a time. Merge this 2 and do a new check for duplicates.

Thanks to "a-horse-with-no-name" for all new approaches.